# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined using jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

i tried to apply validation system use jQuery for upload image and multiple images, check file extension and file size but it gives me error `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

hi, i tried to apply validation system use jQuery for upload image and multiple images, check file extension and file size but it gives me error `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: true,
            success: "valid"
          });
          $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
              "image": {
                  extension: "jpg|jpeg|png|gif",
                  filesize:    "2048"
              },
              "images[]": {
                  extension: "jpg|jpeg|png|gif",
                  filesize:    "2048"
              },

            }
          });
   
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>rules</title>
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.2/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="myform">
    
        <div class="form-group" id="divim">
            <label>image annonce<span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" required autocomplete="image">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="divims">
            <label>images annonce<span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
            <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control @error('images') is-invalid @enderror" required autocomplete="images" multiple>
        </div>
    
        <button class="btn btn-theme">valider</button>
        </form>
     </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Running your code, I see the following exception being thrown:

```
Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'extension' method. TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

It seems like the extension method isn't included in the validate plugin by default. **It's a separate script you need to include in your html.**

Including `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.2/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>` fixed it for me.

Browsing the documentation of the jQuery validation plugin, I didn't see a method for `filesize`. See https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/ to create one yourself. Should be straightforward.

For example:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, arg) {
  // value -> name of the file being uploaded
  // element.files[0].size -> size of file being uploaded
  // arg -> 2048
  // Do some validation of filesize and return true or false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your additional-methods.js file.

```
$.validator.addMethod('fileSize', function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
}, 'default message');
```